# Google Glass streaming video refresh rate

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-glass, rtsp

I am developing a Google Glass application.
One of the things I want to do is to stream a video (RTSP) to a google glass activity.
I wrote a program that does that based on this guide - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888

And it works!

The only problem i have is that it takes a few seconds for each update of the video to appear on the glass.. What am I doing wrong?

The only idea I have is to use a `LiveCard` and render the image there. Maybe `LiveCard` should work faster? any thoughts?

Thanks!